# Why was Set left out of .NET Collections?

Tags: .net, collections, set

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why doesn’t .Net have a Set data structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433695/why-doesnt-net-have-a-set-data-structure)
>   [C# Set collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183685/c-set-collection)

Just curious as to why Sets were left out of .NET collections. It seems like a pretty big omission, and I wondered what the reason might be.

BTW I know that there is HashSet in .NET 3.5, but it did take Microsoft a long time to get around to putting it in!

Comment: Discussion of sets here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183685/c-set-collection

Comment: This kind of 'Why' questions is usually pointless. There are other ADTs missing, it's a matter of (expected) demand and resources.

Comment: Dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433695/why-doesnt-net-have-a-set-data-structure

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the "why" - and I suspect no-one will - but I just thought I'd mentioned that in .NET 4.0 there will finally be an [`ISet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081(VS.100).aspx) interface type - implemented by `HashSet<T>` and `SortedSet<T>`.

Comment: What I found interesting, is that the LINQ team decided to implement their own Set collection, rather than use `HashSet`. See the `Distinct` extension method.

Comment: @Thorarin: Indeed. My guess is that this is just a lighter-weight implementation - there are various things it doesn't need to implement, because it only needs to worry about one use case.